# Passive linear circuit to generate high-voltage spikes from a 10 V peak-to-peak square wave

Tags: analog, circuit-design, ltspice

How to implement a passive linear cırcuıt to generate high-voltage spikes from a 10 V peak-to-peak square wave with a source resistance of 50 Ω with a frequency of less than 5 MHz?

Peak value of the voltage spikes must be 20 V ≤ Vpeak ≤ 25 V. Full width at half maximum must be less than 100 nanoseconds (∆t < 100 ns).

The spikes don't need to be square-shaped. We can assume the rise and fall times of the square wave are 10 ns.

Important: spike duration should be much shorther than the input period.

How can I implement such a circuit (in LTspice)?

Comment: perhaps with a charge-pump type circuit based on [this principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator)? Otherwise with a transformer and capacitive coupling

Answer (score 1):

The specifications do not mention an output impedance. Nor do they mention whether the spikes need to be unipolar, or whether they can have one polarity on the rising edge of the input, and the opposite polarity on the falling edge of the input.

Despite the ambiguities, I have a circuit composed of purely passive components that may (or may not!) meet the stated (or unstated!) requirements. At least this will get one started.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpPNqZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here are the input and output voltages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use passive devices, you're essentially limited to RLC (and some other things like diodes). Here are ways you can implement the different parts of the design. It sounds like a homework assignment, so I'll at least point you to some resources that you can assemble and test in LTspice.

First, there's a discrepancy between the input voltage and the output voltage. If you can only use passive devices, you can use some kind of voltage multiplier: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/voltage-multiplier-circuit.html Those examples will turn your 10 V square wave in to 30 V, recharging every cycle.

Once you have a capacitor charged up to 30ish V, you can discharge that capacitor to generate a pulse. As long as you have input square waves coming in, the capacitor will charge, and you can discharge it again. The values of C and R can then be chosen to get the right pulse width and output impedance.

As a side note: I accidentally made one of these pulse sources while trying to make a super-fast PTT for radio digital modes. If the discharge time is too fast, it just pulses every period of the input wave. Slow down the discharge time, and it will just hold a mostly constant voltage as long as your square wave source is on. In my case, I fed that in to a transistor switch, but in your case, that will be your output.